# Date in Java is always 1 hour out?

Tags: java, android, time

I'm currently experimenting to achieve the following purpose:

- I am creating an android app to help me manage rotas at work. More a project in spare time then to really help.
- For each employee, I can set a start and end time as a string in the following format: "HH:mm".
- I need to work out the total hours and then work out the total hours including breaks.
- Below, if someone worked more than 3 hours and 45 minutes but less than 6 hours I want them to have a 15 minute break.
- Example would be, if someone works 4 hours ( total hours 04:00 ) they would get a 15 minute break ( hours including breaks 03:45).

**Problem**: Currently if I set hours to start at 06:00 and finish at 10:00 I want it to give me total hours as 4 hours and including breaks as 3 hours and 45 minutes. It is actually giving me the total hours as 5 and the hours including breaks as 5 hours and 45 minutes.

```
private String calcDiffInHoursAsString(Date start, Date finish){
    try{
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        long diffInMillis =    finish.getTime() - start.getTime();
        Date diffAsDate = new Date(diffInMillis);
        String diffAsHours = formatter.format(diffAsDate);

        return diffAsHours;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return "";
    }
}

private Date calcDiffInHoursAsDate(Date start, Date finish){
    try{
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        long diffInMillis =    finish.getTime() - start.getTime();
        Date diffAsDate = new Date(diffInMillis);

        return diffAsDate;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return new Date();
    }
}

private String calcHoursToString(String start, String finish){
    if (!(start == "00:00" && finish == "00:00")){

        try{
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date startTime = formatter.parse(start);
            Date finishTime = formatter.parse(finish);

            Date HoursExcBreaks = calcDiffInHoursAsDate(startTime, finishTime);
            String HoursExcBreaksAsString = calcDiffInHoursAsString(startTime, finishTime);
            Log.d("Difference exc. Breaks", HoursExcBreaksAsString);

            // Breaks:
            // < 4 hours - No Break
            // 4 - 6 hours - 15 Minutes
            // 6 - 8 hours - 30 Minutes
            // 8 - 9 hours - 45 Minutes

            // Work out actual hours after breaks

            // If HoursExcBreaks > 03:45 and HoursExcBreaks < 06:00 then take 00:15 break...
            if (HoursExcBreaks.before(formatter.parse("06:00")) && HoursExcBreaks.after(formatter.parse("03:45"))){
                long millisecondsIncBreak = HoursExcBreaks.getTime() - formatter.parse("00:15").getTime();
                Date dateIncBreak = new Date(millisecondsIncBreak);
                String hoursIncBreak = formatter.format(dateIncBreak);

                Log.d("Shift Inc Breaks", hoursIncBreak );
            }


        }catch(Exception ex){
            Context context = getActivity();
            CharSequence text = ex.getMessage();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

    }

    return "";
}
```

So when I call:

```
calcHoursToString("06:00", "10:00" );
```

I get the shift length including the breaks as 03:45 in a string.

Truth is, I'm not even sure this is the best way to work it out? It's probably not! :)

Comment: Just curious, what time-zone are you in?

Comment: You don't show how you get the inputs and what value they have.  I can assure you that the basic calculations work so it must be your input values and/or reasoning.  Best approach is to step through with the debugger and examine the values.  I think you will find that they are not what you think they are.  You can also copy/paste into Excel (or similar) to verify the calculations.

Comment: @Simon I can also assure you that they don't. I've tried taking the inputs out completely and putting the value in to the java but it came with the same result. The first thing I checked was that it was getting the right data from the inputs. As you can see above, I've ignored the inputs completely for now and put the strings in myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
long diffInMillis = finish.getTime() - start.getTime();
Date diffAsDate = new Date(diffInMillis);
```

You're using java.util.Date to represent a duration, instead of an absolute point in time, which will cause all kinds of problems. Specifically, in this case, when you do new Date(diffInMillies), diffInMillis is interpreted in the context of UTC, which is probably not the timezone you're in...

Don't use Date to represent durations! Just leave it as a primitive type like int or long, meaning a number of milliseconds.

If you want to format the duration nicely you'll have to do that manually, or as pointed out by others you can use a framework such as [JODA](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which has built in classes for durations.

Comment: Do you have any examples turning two strings like 12:00 and 14:00 in to the difference between them using Joda? I can find lots of ways to compare two dates with Joda but not to compare two times?

Comment: You should be able to figure that out by reading the Javadoc. I don't actually have experience with Joda-Time myself, but a quick glance seems to indicate that something like this should work:  
  
`LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("12:00"); LocalTime finish = LocalTime.parse("14:00"); long difference = finish.getMillisOfDay() - start.getMillisOfDay();`  
  
I would keep the value as a long as much as possible, especially to do calculations with. To format it as a string, look at the `Duration` and `PeriodFormatter/PeriodFormatterBuilder` classes.

Comment: Great answer with follow up. Thanks for the help, I've always hated working with times in any code.

Comment: No problem! Always remember that Date (and Calendar) is an absolute point in time (a point on the time line), not a relative time (such as a time of day) or duration. Trying to use them as such will cause much pain. ;) You can get a long way with vanilla Java by using ints or longs, representing a number of milliseconds, for relative times and durations, that's what I usually do. And don't forget to account for timezones when converting to and from Calendars. But frameworks like Joda do make some things easier.

Answer (score 1):

Alex,

one the best framework used to evaluate differences between dates is [JODA](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Eg.

```
Hours.between(startDate, endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not taking into account the timezone... as soon as you start working on date conversion (converting long time value into Date) you need to take the timezone into account. If you're doing some difference between 2 dates which are not set on the same TimeZone this is exactly what can happen.